# Conditional zip of two lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to zip together two lists to create a new dictionary. List one is a list of column names represented as string, while list two is a list of variables.

If the variable is empty (None) I don't want it or the corresponding column data (they share the same index, so the 'foo' column is at index 0 and so is the 'foo' variable) within my dict.

I've tried a few ways to construct this using dict comprehension but haven't  been able to properly create it.

My dict needs to be ordered so I'm using the OrderedDict module as well.

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT:

Here's how the data should look.

```
list_1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'whatever']
list_2 = [foo, bar, baz, whatever]
```

Now lets imagine that the whatever variable is None.

The dict, I create should then look like

```
d = { 
'foo' : foo,
'bar' : bar,
'baz' : baz
}
```

Comment: Please show us an example input, your desired output, your attempt at solving this, and specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: `OrderedDict({ k: v for k, v in zip(l1, l2) if k is not None })` ?

Comment: @ap: that won't work, as you constructed a dictionary first destroying the order. It is `OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in zip(l1, l2) if k is not None)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh duh, obviously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Martijn points out in the comments, you just want `OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in zip(list_1, list_2) if v is not None)`.

Comment: you want `if v is not None` rather than `if k is not None` - read the question carefully.